# Открыть скрипт R, чтобы получить графики из BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, r, benchmark

Чтобы проверить производительность и скорость работы методов, использовала [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), вот на [Хабр-е еще интересная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/277177/)

```cs
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp31)]
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Summary result = BenchmarkRunner.Run<LinqVSForeach>();
    }
}

[RPlotExporter] // чтобы скрипт для графиков получить 
public class LinqVSForeach
{
    private List<Object> objects;
    
    [Params(1000, 10000)]
    public int N;
    
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        objects = Enumerable.Range(1, N).Select(index => new Object { Id = index, Name = $"Object n°{index}" }).ToList();
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public List<Task> Linq()
    {
        return objects.Select(o => ProcessObject(o)).ToList();
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public List<Task> ForEach()
    {
        var objectsTask = new List<Task>();
    
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            objectsTask.Add(ProcessObject(obj));
        }
        return objectsTask;
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public List<Task> YieldReturn()
    {
        return Yield(objects).ToList();
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<Task> Yield(List<Object> objects)
    {
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            yield return ProcessObject(obj);
        }
    }
    
    public Task ProcessObject(Object obj)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

на выходе получаю результат в консоли [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а также файлы результаты в различных форматах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В том числе и скрипт R, который я знаю что если суметь раскрыть то можно получить графики, но у меня не получается ни отрыть ни запустить ни найти сами графики... загрузила R, посмотрела почитала, пока не могу, может кто знает,

**подскажите как открыть, как раскодировать этот скрипт на языке R**

Comment: если не хочется ничего загружать и устанавливать, то сам файл со скриптом можно открыть любым текстовым редактором (в том числе и студией), скопировать код и выполнить его в колабе https://colab.to/r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить [R](https://cran.cmm.msu.ru/), затем:

1. Правой кнопкой по `BuildPlots.R`
2. Открыть с помощью...
3. Выбрать приложение
4. `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe`

При первом запуске, R установит дополнительные пакеты. Повторно запустить скрипт можно просто двойным кликом, и он нагенерит картинок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]